# netbeans and Apache Derby Embedded + spring

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, derby

I'm using netbeans 6.7 on windows.I've been using DerbyClient in my spring test project and  i've successfully change the driverClassName from org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver to org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.I was formally browsing through the bd from the service tab of netbeans.Now that i've changed the connection to Embedded where do i verify access the database to be able to browse through it?
thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. That is the whole idea of **Embedded**. The only application that has access
to the database is the one that embeds it. So unless you *embed* the database in Netbeans
itself you cannot browse it as before.